# Prove $v$ is not surjective

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Let$ v$ : $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$
 be a differentiable function such that the velocity vector $\cfrac{dv}{
dt}\neq 0$  at all $t\in \mathbb R$. Prove
that $v$ is not surjective.

I tried to work with definition and tried to prove contrapositive statement but It get me nowhere. Could anyone give me a hint to start with (not solution).

Comment: Interesting problem. Maybe you can show that the image of $v$ has measure 0 (or even just finite measure) by bounding it within a thin region (that gets thinner when $t$ is farther from 0 so that its total area is a convergent sum).

Comment: i cant even find a surjective function from $R$ into $R^{2}$

Comment: @Mohammer M.Zerrak check space filling curve

Comment: You don't need the condition on the velocity vector. There is no surjective differentiable function from $\mathbf{R}^m$ to $\mathbf{R}^n$ when $m<n$. This appears e.g. as an exercise (with substantial hints!) in chapter 1 of Warner's excellent book *Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups*.

Comment: You should look into Sards theorem.

Comment: What is your definition of "differentiable"? Is it $C^1$ or just has derivative at every point?

Comment: I think just derivative exists at all points

Comment: @CloudJR: I assume this is coming from you class notes: I suggest you check what exactly did your professor say. The point is that there are several proofs: One can argue that the image $v(R)$ will have Lebesgue measure 0 in $R^2$, this does not need $v'(t)\ne 0$ assumption. Or, you use the $C^1$-immersion theorem to argue that for small intervals $I$, $v(I)$ is the graph of a function and then use Baire Category theorem. But this needs $C^1$ assumption. Or, if you just discussed Sard's theorem, then this is what you should be using: This again needs $C^1$ but  not $v'(t)\ne 0$.

Comment: @Stephen: Are you sure Werner does not assume $C^1$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan In fact I'm sure he *does* assume $C^1$ but I had forgotten. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephen: This does make a difference. The claim still holds for everywhere differentiable maps but a proof is more difficult.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan this question doesn't come from my class notes  it was in a question paper GS2019 part 2

Comment: Here is the link 2019 question paper problem 7 http://www.math.tifr.res.in/graduate/entrance.php

Comment: Any idea how to prove image is a set of measure 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: {\mathbb R}^m\to {\mathbb R}^n$ be a map differentiable everywhere, $m< n$. I will identify  ${\mathbb R}^m$ with a linear subspace $E$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$. Then $mes(E)=0$ where $mes$ is the Lebesgue measure on ${\mathbb R}^n$. Now, apply Lemma 7.25 from  W.Rudin, "Real and Complex analysis" (3rd edition). Since $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $E$, the assumption of Lemma 7.25 holds: One only needs
$$
\forall x\in E, \limsup_{y\to x} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}<\infty. 
$$
Hence, $mes (f(E))=0$. Thus, $f$ cannot be surjective. qed

No idea, why do they assume nonzero derivative (maybe just to confuse you).

The bottom line: If you want to get to TIFR, make sure you know Rudin's book really well.

**Edit.** 1. Robert Israel gives a proof of the relevant result from Rudin (for $m=1$) [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201424/proof-that-no-differentiable-space-filling-curve-exists). The proof is quite short and is essentially the same as the one in Rudin's book.

2. While the original space-filling curves were nowhere differentiable, Lebesgue constructed a space-filling curve which is **almost everywhere differentiable** (with Holder exponent arbitrarily close to $1/2$), see 
   Theorem 5.4.2 in

H.Sagan, "Space-filling curves," Springer-Verlag, 1984.

3. Here is an alternative (longer!) proof which uses the assumption that $v$ is $C^1$and $v'(t)\ne 0$ for all $t$. I will give this proof as a sequence of steps which you should be able to manage yourself (in fact, if you want to get to TIFR, you should not need these hints).

a. Argue that $v$ is locally injective.

b. Prove that for every finite subinterval $I\subset {\mathbb R}$, $v(I)$ has empty interior.

c. Conclude by using Baire's Theorem.

Comment: That means derivative not equal 0 is not necessary.  But with that hypothesis  does it makes proof any simpler.  I ask this because this is one of the top institute for mathematics and if they ask then there might be something in that

Comment: @CloudJR: No, Rudin's proof does not get simpler (and it is already quite simple if you know what you are doing). It is possible that they had in mind a totally different proof.

Comment: which rudin u mention ? Baby rudin or real and complex analysis

Comment: @CloudJR It is written in my answer.

Comment: @CloudJR: Did you understand the answer?

Comment: "in fact, if you want to get to TIFR, you should not need these hints" I may able to prove it but within 30 min... Hopefully not

Comment: @CloudJR Good luck on your exam! TIFR is the best place in India for pure math.

Comment: Thank you. I will give my best.

Comment: may I know where you are studying/working?

Comment: @CloudJR: No, sorry: I prefer to keep my anonymity. One thing I can say, I am not based in India.